# Plotting a normal curve on top of a weighted histogram

Tags: r, normal-distribution, weighted

I have a dataset which requires me to plot a **weighted** histogram because of the data

```
gridcellname  value  avg.temp
Y55X21          4,84    4,09
Y56X17          0       5,34
Y44X44          2,75    1,8
Y46X38          3,68    3,4
Y58X19          4,32    5,08
Y59X17          0       4,8
Y60X20          5,29    5,27
Y61X18          0       5,15
Y62X21          5,59    5,09
Y63X19          3,05    5,47
Y64X22          2,75    5,04
Y65X25          4,82    4,54
Y66X22          0       4,54
```

I use a weighted histogram and breaks from

```
H <- weighted.hist(df$avg.temp, df$value, ylim=c(0,120), breaks=c(seq(-1.5,8.5, by=0.5)))
```

OR

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x=temp_category)) + stat_summary(fun.y="sum", geom="bar")
```

This gives me a nice graph but I am unable to draw a normal curve on top of it. As you can see from the 2 plots, I may not have data in the (-1.5,-1) category but I would still nevertheless like to plot it and also keep my yaxis range (0,120) although my max values are around ~40.

I have tried these 2 codes for adding the curve but it is not entirely correct

```
xfit<-seq(min(df$value),max(df$value)) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(df$value),sd=sd(df$value)) 
yfit <- yfit*diff(H$mids[1:2])*length(df$value) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

This curve seems to be on the left of my plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x=temp_category)) + stat_summary(fun.y="sum", geom="bar") + stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(df$value), sd=sd(df$value)))
```

This gives me an almost flat horizontal line to the x axis.

Thank you!

Comment: please start a new R session and run the code you posted here: Your example is not reproducible! How is temp_category computed?

Comment: You do not need gridcellname is this example. You could just have a random file with values and avg.temp just like the one above. 

    df$temp_category <- cut(df$avg.temp, breaks=c(seq(-1.5,8.5,by=0.5)))

Comment: it appears to be a flat line, because your bars are in absolut frequencies with a max of 21 and your `dnorm` has a max of ~ 0.2

Comment: but if i use a weighted hist and the xfit,yfit... then u can actually see i am getting what i want... except that it is on the left side... to ask simply, is it possible to draw a curve/line on a weighted histogram?

Comment: what do you mean by "if I use weighted hist"? `H <- weighted.hist(...` doesn't produce a plot for me...

Comment: do you use `weighted.hist` from the `plotrix` package?

Comment: yup i use it from plotrix